# group_by output conversion to data frame issues

Tags: python, pandas, merge, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

So I am not sure if I am taking the best approach to solve this problem, but this is what I have so far:
This is the df that I am working with:

```
calls.head()

id  user_id call_date   duration
0   1000_93     1000    2018-12-27  9.0
1   1000_145    1000    2018-12-27  14.0
2   1000_247    1000    2018-12-27  15.0
3   1000_309    1000    2018-12-28  6.0
4   1000_380    1000    2018-12-30  5.0
```

I am trying to figure out how to create a data frame that tells me how many times a user made a call in a month. This is the code I used to generate that:

```
calls_per_month = calls.groupby(['user_id',calls['call_date'].dt.month])['call_date'].count()
calls_per_month.head(10)
user_id  call_date
1000     12            16
1001     8             27
         9             49
         10            65
         11            64
         12            56
1002     10            11
         11            55
         12            47
1003     12           149
Name: call_date, dtype: int64
```

Now, the issue is that I need to do further calculations with the user_id attributes of other data frames, so I need to be able to access the total I computed in this table. However it seems like the table I created is not a dataframe, which is not allowing me to do so. This is a solution I tried:

```
calls_per_month = calls.groupby(['user_id',calls['call_date'].dt.month])['call_date'].count().reset_index()
#(calls_per_month.to_frame()).columns = ['user_id','date','total_calls']
calls_per_month.columns = ['user_id','date','total_calls']
```

(I tried with and without to_frame)
But I got the following error:
cannot insert call_date, already exists

Please suggest the best way to go about solving this issue. Considering that I have other dataframes with user_id and attributes like 'data used' how do I make this data frame such that I can do computations like total_use = calls['total_calls']*internet['data_used] for each user_id?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rename` for change level name, so [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) working correctly:

```
calls_per_month = (calls.groupby(['user_id',
                                  calls['call_date'].dt.month.rename('month')])['call_date']
                        .count()
                        .reset_index())
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this solves my issue. Will need  to see how this solution works with my further calculations.